# Where clause on model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have below where clause:

```
users.joins(:role).where("roles like :search OR email like :search OR first_name like :search OR last_name like :search", 
        search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
```

I want to be able to query `roles` table `name` column.

This doesn't seem to work.

Is there a good way to achieve this containing all other conditions in the above?

Comment: roles is a join table

Comment: `ERROR:  column "roles" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY roles desc LIMIT 1...`

Comment: how users and roles are connected ?

Comment: Show the structure of `\d "users"` in `psql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  users.joins(:role).where("roles.name like :search OR email like :search OR first_name like :search OR last_name like :search", 
    search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
```